# In PyCharm how can I move the text to the left? I don't like it in the center

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I would like to see all the code text on the left when I open PyCharm. I don't like that the code is all placed in the center. I would like to move it to the left. How can I?

There are no spaces before the code. It happens to all PyCharm files. The same files, if imported into another editor, have the code positioned on the left and there is no space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are those actual spaces? Can you save the file as it is and open it in another editor and see if it exists? Does it happen to all files or only certain files? Cause I don't have these issue in my PyCharm, both Community Edition and Professional.

Comment: @Alraj There are no spaces before the code. It happens to all PyCharm files. The same files, if imported into another editor, have the code positioned on the left and there is no space. I have just installed Pycharm and have been playing around for a while. Maybe I touched some mistakes

Comment: I've never seen this happening in PyCharm - but you should perhaps not crop your screenshot as much. Your gutter looks strange and there's some sort of bar or ruler over your file that's not there by default. Have you tried uninstalling PyCharm, removing its settings, reinstalling and creating a new project without first installing plugins or importing settings? It looks like you may be using a plugin that's not compatible with your version of PyCharm. Provide a wider and higher screenshot, showing more of the interface, and perhaps the problem will be more apparent.

Comment: @Grismar
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm, but I always get the same problem. I removed the settings too. I have updated my question with a second larger screenshot

Comment: Check what modes you have got there in `Main Menu | View | Appearance` -- if you have any that start with "Exit xxx" -- use them. Because this looks like you have entered the Distraction Free mode and then restored toolbars/toolwindows manually instead of properly exiting the mode.

Comment: If you do not have any of them started with `Exit...`, use `Enter Distraction Free mode` and then `Exit Distraction Free mode` after that. Any better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [distraction free (view-)mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/distraction-free/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20switch%20to%20the,all%20the%20UI%20elements%20hidden.) is active. 
Try `View > Appearance > Exit Distraction free mode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a plain Python file looks like in a fairly standard installation of PyCharm.

[image]

Note how there's no ruler over the editor, where yours appears to have one, and the gutter is coloured differently, while yours looks wide and has the same colour as the editor.

Your configuration is certainly not the default installation with a new default project. Perhaps you installed some sort of theme, or plugin that modifies the look?

Comment: I have not installed anything